# Retrieve Firestore Data From Multiple Collections

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

**Overview**

I am writing a flutter screen that showcases their saved quizzes for the respective user. I have been successful in retrieving the list of quiz references for a user, however I have been unsuccessful in retrieving the quiz data in the list of references.

**Goal**

Ultimately, I hope to display the retrieved data in a `ListView.builder()`, however successfully retrieving the data is the main goal.

**Firestore Setup**

Each document in the "User" collection represents a user for the application. Users have an array of references that point to the respective quiz created by them. Each document in the "Quiz" collection, represent a singular quiz.

[image: User Firestore Collection]

[image: Quiz Firestore Collection]

**Current Code**

```
//main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'temp.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: "SCRUM",
      home: GetUserName("eQxkFJZ7XOf73weUkjZzYQHCBw72"),
    ),
  );
}
```

```
//temp.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class GetUserName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;

  GetUserName(this.documentId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('User');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          List<dynamic> quizRefs = data['Quizzes'];
          return Text("My: ${data['Quizzes']} ");
        }
        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, but "I have been unsuccessful" is really hard to help with. What happens when you run this code? Is there an error message? If not, what does it show in the app? And in its logging output? --- It's also typically helpful if you debug locally and tell us the result of that. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hello and sorry for the confusion. Currently:

1) No error messages arise

2) Program outputs `[DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>(Quiz/iSNtL1SYY5kpTcKbtEsS), DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>(Quiz/
n6HWnSOWmR9pUjISKd7J)]`, the string references to the quiz I want to retrieve data from.

3) There is no implementation for the retrieval of the second collection ("Quiz"), as I am unsure how to go about this since I have already used a `FutureBuilder()` once already.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Quizzes` field in your `User` document is an array of document references. Firestore does not automatically load the data from a referenced document, so when you load the `User` document, its `Quizzes` field is exposed as an array of `DocumentReference` values.

To load the actual quiz they refer to, you have to call `get()` or `snapshots()` on each of them, which then triggers an additional load/listen for the quiz data itself. To display that in the array, you'll need a `FutureBuilder` (when you use `get()`) or a `StreamBuilder` (when you use `snapshots`).